# Keeping c3p0 connections alive

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, c3p0

I'm using `unreturnedConnectionTimeout="1800"` and `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces="true"` to release forgotten connections.
But sometimes the application is still alive but there is no activity to the database. The c3p0 connection pool will close the connection after 1800 seconds. As soon as I start using the old entityManager again it complains that the connection is closed.
I tried sending a native query (`SELECT NOW()`) to the entityManager every couple of minutes but that does not keep the c3p0 connection alive. Maybe native queries bypass c3p0???

I like to keep '`unreturnedConnectionTimeout`' as a fail save but also would like to be able to keep valid connections alive.

How can I solve this?

Thanks,
Milo

EDIT:
Seems that the c3p0 connection cannot be kept alive after the `unreturnedConnectionTimeout`. It does not look to activity but just the creation time. Now I'm looking for api access to c3p0 to update the creation time... Bah, dirty...

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you are keeping Connections checked out for a very long time. that's not a good idea with a Connection pool. Connections (or Hibernate sessions) should be acquired on an as-needed basis, used, and then closed immediately rather than being held alive and open.

this is an architectural issue more than a configuration problem.

good luck!

Comment: Thanks and I completely agree. But the application is designed this wrong way and changing it is to much work at the moment.

Comment: life is like that... but if Connections will be held checked out for long periods of time in the normal course of operations, you won't be able to use unreturnedConnectionTimeout as a failsafe. by setting an unreturnedConnectionTimout, you are informing c3p0 of the maximum time period a Connection might be checked out in legitimate, nonpathological use cases. if Connections are being held open indefinitely by your application, then there is no length of time that would not be legitimate.

Comment: Luckely for me the connections are closed as soon as a user stores something or switches to another page in the application. I set the timeout to 4 hours what seems to function good enough.
What I find strange is that c3p0 does not check for activity before throwing it away. I'm going to create a question for that.